# JDBC / Oracle Double value insertion fails

Tags: oracle, jdbc, double

I got the following problem at hand. We try to insert a Double via JDBC in Oracle 11.2.0.2.0, we send 70.56 and in the database 70,56000000000000227373675443232059478759 is inserted. My question would be why? Can someone please point me in the right direction, should I switch to float, I suspect a JDBC mapping problem.

Comment: Here we go again. [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: what can I do to prevent this?

Comment: I´m afraid this is no option for us.